# Can function in Swift return different data types?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm working with `UITableView` in `Swift` and I have a function that returns number of rows based on some conditions and another function that returns title for every section. Both functions have the same body, the same conditions, but first function returns `Int` dat type and second returns `String` data type.

Can I somehow make this one generic function, to be one that returns some generic value but that value must be 'Int' for first function and `String` for second function.

The code below is the function that returns number of rows. Same body goes for function that returns title for section. And its return type is `String`.

```
func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> Int {

    let parameters = SuggestionsTableSectionType.Parameters(recents: recents, suggestions: suggestions, section: section)

    if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return recents.count
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.suggestionsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return suggestions.count
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSuggestionsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return recents.count
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSuggestionsAndSectionIsOne(parameters).isActive {
        return suggestions.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Modify your function to return a tuple or a struct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return the `tuple` type like this:

```
func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> (Int, String) {}
```

Also, for convention your code, you can use `typealias` keyword to define name for your `tuple`:

```
typealias NumberOfRowsInfo = (row: Int, someString: String)

func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> NumberOfRowsInfo {}
```

And get data like this:

```
let info = getNumberOfRows(for: section)
print("Row: \(info.row), string: \(info.someString)")
```

Comment: This looks ok. I'll try with that. Also, every answer here is correct and I can see the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use same function with two different return types like this

`func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> (Int,String)`

Then it's invoked as

```
let (yourIntegerValue,yourStringValue) = getNumberOfRows(for section:yourSectionNumber)
```

Now use these two values to perform your task.

Answer (score 2):

You can return `tuple`

`func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> (row:Int,title:String)`

and  `return` like this  `return(row:suggestions.count,title:"Suggestions")`

and you can use

```
let tupple =  getNumberOfRows(for :0) 
tupple.row or  tupple.title
```

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you for [tuple](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-tuple).

**You can do with tuple something like this:**

```
func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> (Int,String) {
    return (5,"5")
}

getNumberOfRows(for: 3).0
getNumberOfRows(for: 3).1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following way:

```
func getNumberOfRows(for section: Int) -> (Int, String) {

    let parameters = SuggestionsTableSectionType.Parameters(recents: recents, suggestions: suggestions, section: section)

    if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return (recents.count, "Some String")
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.suggestionsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return (suggestions.count, "Some String")
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSuggestionsAndSectionIsZero(parameters).isActive {
        return (recents.count, "Some String")
    } else if SuggestionsTableSectionType.recentsAndSuggestionsAndSectionIsOne(parameters).isActive {
        return (suggestions.count, "Some String")
    }
    return (0, "Some String")
}
```

Comment: I refactored it like that and i works like a charm. Thank you very much for you answers and suggestions.